# TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher enabling SSL TLS 1.3 with Docker container with java embedded

Tags: docker, ssl, encryption, openssl

The problem I want solved, is I want to use the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher suite available in JAVA with TLS 1.3.

If you run the keytool -showinfo –tls, command, I want to see the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher in JAVA 14.

I then want to enable the export restrictions to enable the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher that is available from Oracle.

I want TLS 1.3 with SSL support in JAVA 14, and a Docker file that supports SSL with this cipher suite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

I want a docker file that enables the export restricted ciphers, and can run securely with SSL  inside a docker container.

Ultimately, OpenSSL should be able to connect to the Docker container that is built, to perform a connection test.

https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/cipher-suites-algorithms-security-settings/
TLS 1.3 Cipher Suite List
Here are the five TLS 1.3 cipher suites that are supported by OpenSSL right now.
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256

See example Docker file that inserts certs:  (https://rootsquash.com/inserting-certificates-into-java-keystore-via-dockerfile/)
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7.1

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

COPY ./certs/My_Root_CA.cer /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY ./certs/My_Issuing_CA.cer /etc/ssl/certs/

RUN yum clean all && \
    yum --releasever=7.1 swap -y -- remove systemd-container* -- install systemd systemd-libs && \
    yum update -y --releasever=7.1 && \
    yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk --releasever=7.1 -y && \
    yum clean all && \
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -storepasswd -new mysecretpassword -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit && \
    echo "yes" | $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /etc/ssl/certs/My_Root_CA.cer -alias my-root-ca -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass mysecretpassword && \
    echo "yes" | $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /etc/ssl/certs/My_Issuing_CA.cer -alias my-issuing-ca -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass mysecretpassword && \
    rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/My_Root_CA.cer &&\
    rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/My_Issuing_CA.cer

Comment: There are no longer export restrictions aka 'limited policy' on (Oracle) Java crypto since 8u161 more than two years ago. Java 11 up supports TLS1.3 with the ciphersuite you want (and 2 others), though only 13 and 14 have `keytool -showinfo` to display info about it. How to get Java in your docker I can't help you with. Note for OpenSSL to do TLS1.3 it must be 1.1.1.